# Why is Edmond Karps faster than Ford-Fulkerson?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, ford-fulkerson, edmonds-karp

Why choosing the shortest augmentation path everytime instead of an arbitrary augmentation path makes the Edmond Karps algorithm faster than Ford-Fulkerson

Comment: It's not necessarily faster. That depends entirely on the maximum flow in the graph and the number of vertices and edges.

Comment: I still don't understand what Ford Fulkerson complexity has to do with the max flow, because ford increases the flow at every chosen path with the minimum capacity in that path

Comment: Did you read the complexity analysis for both algorithm? Analyzing there time complexity rigorously is pretty much the only way to understand why one of them is faster.